# PHP Emailing incorrect Links

Tags: php, email, url, hyperlink

I have a simple php emailing script that sends out various email campaigns to our subscribers. However, every once in a while, a link that I am trying to send in the email gets corrupted.

For example, this link here:
http://www.classicalsinger.com/images/CS_July_2012.pdf

In some emails gets turned into this:
http://lajokoduwo.cwahi.net/ti-89-titanium-and-vista.php

Does anyone have any idea why that might happen?

Comment: It's really hard to tell what's going on here without seeing what your script does. Could you post the relevant portion of the script?

Maybe you have a virus that intercepts outgoing mail and inserts its own links?

Comment: is the link that it gets changes in to a link you would insert else where? or is it totally our of the blue?

Comment: this looks like its programmed into it. Too specific to be an error. Its not a bug, its a feature!